# How to use CLi and html errors in error folder in Codeigniter 2.2?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-datamapper

I've updated Codeigniter 1.1.4 to 2.2 right now But I got many concern about my acknowledge on this new and I don't know how to use Errors folder that I found in this new version

1, I've found a few file in the Errors folder

```
             1:error_404.php
             2:error_db.php
             3:error_general.php
             4:error_php.php
```

And the Errors folder was exist in application folder 
And in View folder have:

```
    cli:  
             1:error_404.php
             2:error_db.php
             3:error_general.php
             4:error_php.php
             5:index.html
 HTML:  
             1:error_404.php
             2:error_db.php
             3:error_general.php
             4:error_php.php
             5:index.html
```

However My source of website directory is like this

```
http://localhost/Codeigniter2.2/public_html
```

But My System and Application is root of public_html

```
 Codeigniter2.2/public_html/: 
             .htaccess
             index.php
             And Stylesheet, images folder


 Codeigniter2.2/: *Root of public_html/*

             1,System
             2,Application
```

Because I change the directory of Application and system of Codeigniter to

```
    $system_path = '../system';
    $application_folder = '../application';
```

So What I got the errors is like this

```
         **A PHP Error was encountered
         Severity: Warning
         Message: include(application/views/errorshtml\error_general.php): failed to open    stream: No such file or directory
        Filename: core/Exceptions.php
        Line Number: 169**
```

When I call wrong method or function in controller

Please help me

Thanks for help me I will Vote and share your answer

Comment: Help me Please !!!!!!!

Comment: Why? I ccan't get any answer? How can I do

Answer (score 0):

errors which are in cli will be called when you get errors on command line